# Does MUI have a form component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a form with multiple `FormControl` (https://mui.com/api/form-control/) components and I have them wrapped in a:

```
const FormBody = styled(Box)(() => ({
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
}));
```

```
<FormBody onSubmit={handleSubmitLogin(onLoginSubmit)} component="form">
  <FormControl>
  ...
```

But I was hoping to create some CSS rules in the theme of MUI but I can't find any component that can be used to encapsulate the `FormControl` components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're expecting something like Ant Design's [`Form`](https://ant.design/components/form/#header), then no there isn't any component like that, just use the native `form` element or `Box component='form'` to easily customize the styles.